# UWP Exception occurs in release build, Debug build works fine

Tags: exception, uwp, release

With the release build app get installed. But when I run the app I get the following exception. But it works fine in the debug build.

> System.Reflection.MissingMetadataException:
>   Reflection_InsufficientMetadata_NoHelpAvailable: EETypeRva:0x00093618.
>   For more information, visit
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=623485
>       at SharedLibrary!+0x6171de
>       at SharedLibrary!+0x472787
>       at System.Reflection.TypeInfo.get_IsVisible()
>       at CMSWindowsApp!+0x9afe7c
>         at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.DynamicProxyMetaObject.BuildCallMethodWithResult(String
>   methodName, Dynamic.DynamicMetaObjectBinder binder,
>   Collections.Generic.IEnumerable
>   args, Dynamic.DynamicMetaObject fallbackResult,
>   Json.Utilities.DynamicProxyMetaObject.Fallback
>   fallbackInvoke)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.DynamicProxyMetaObject.CallMethodWithResult(String
>   methodName, Dynamic.DynamicMetaObjectBinder binder,
>   Collections.Generic.IEnumerable
>   args,
>   Json.Utilities.DynamicProxyMetaObject.Fallback
>   fallback,
>   Json.Utilities.DynamicProxyMetaObject.Fallback
>   fallbackInvoke)
>       at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.DynamicProxyMetaObject.BindGetMember(Dynamic.GetMemberBinder
>   binder)    at
>   System.Dynamic.GetMemberBinder.Bind(Dynamic.DynamicMetaObject target,
>   Dynamic.DynamicMetaObject[] args)    at
>   System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObjectBinder.Bind(Object[] args,
>   Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection
>   parameters, Linq.Expressions.LabelTarget returnLabel)    at
>   SharedLibrary!+0x53c5d2    at
>   SharedLibrary!+0x53c547    at
>   SharedLibrary!+0x522de9    at
>   SharedLibrary!+0x4afb00    at
>   SharedLibrary!+0x45ef1e    at
>   SharedLibrary!+0x6054a3    at
>   SharedLibrary!+0x6056e2    at
>   SharedLibrary!+0x4d8450    at
>   SharedLibrary!+0x4d82cd    at
>   SharedLibrary!+0x38a168    at
>   SharedLibrary!+0x395594    at
>   System.Func.Invoke(AsyncCallback
>   arg1, Object arg2)    at
>   CMSWindowsApp.Screens.URLPage.StoreLocalData(Object resultObj, String
>   url)    at CMSWindowsApp!+0xc0b244    at
>   SharedLibrary!+0x4afb00    at
>   SharedLibrary!+0x45ef1e    at
>   SharedLibrary!+0x605acf    at
>   SharedLibrary!+0x4d8450    at
>   SharedLibrary!+0x4d860d    at
>   SharedLibrary!+0x60536e    at
>   SharedLibrary!+0x6058e7    at
>   SharedLibrary!+0x6064bc    at
>   SharedLibrary!+0x4d8450    at
>   SharedLibrary!+0x4d860d    at
>   CMSWindowsApp!+0x9bc3c7    at
>   System.Action.Invoke(Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite
>   arg1, Screens.Home arg2, Object arg3,
>   Source.ViewModel.AllAssessmentListViewModel arg4)    at
>   CMSWindowsApp!+0xeb73e3

How do I fix this for the release build?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add some entries to the Default.rd.xml file in the Properties folder of your app project.  The UWP release build uses .NET Native where you need to explicitly list the types or namespaces that need to exist for serialization.  [Here is a troubleshooter](https://dotnet.github.io/native/troubleshooter/type.html) that will help you.